# SUBQUERIES with a condition SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to ask for a little help in SQL Server.

I need to sum $ the things that the client bought.

My subquery only sums the total of the entire table, but I need something like

```
Numero D               TotalItem    TotalBOUGHT
-----------------------------------------------
111                     800           1200
111                     200           1200
111                     100           1200
111                     100           1200
455                     200            300
455                     100            300
```

This is my code

```
SELECT
    NumeroD, Descrip AS ClientName, CodClie AS ID, 
    Descrip1 AS Description,  TotalItem, CodUbic, 
    Día_Transaccion AS Day, Mes AS Month, ANO AS YEAR, 
    (SELECT SUM(TotalItem) FROM FORMULAFINAL) AS TotalAmount
FROM 
    FORMULAFINAL 
WHERE 
    Descrip LIKE 'Hector%' 
GROUP BY 
    TotalItem, NumeroD, Descrip, CodClie, Descrip1, 
    TotalItem, CodUbic, Día_Transaccion, Mes, Ano
ORDER BY 
    Ano DESC, NumeroD, Descrip, Descrip1, CodClie, TotalItem, 
    CodUbic, Día_Transaccion, Mes
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtQGX.png)

Comment: Your title says "SQL Server" so why tag MySQL and PostgreSQL too? What RDBMS are you *really* using?

Comment: A mistake Larnu sorryl, I'm using SQL Server

Comment: Also, why the `GROUP BY`; the query with the `GROUP BY` has no aggregation.

Comment: I suspect what you really want is a windowed `SUM`, and no grouping.

Comment: You are right, I deleted the Group By chunk, I let it there because earlier I was Using it.

Comment: I need to sum al the TotalID by the "NumeroD" and the "Day" of transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use windowing functions like below

```
select  
NumeroD, Descrip AS ClientName, CodClie AS ID, Descrip1 AS Description,  TotalItem, CodUbic, Día_Transaccion AS Day, Mes AS Month, ANO AS YEAR, 
    SUM(TotalItem) OVER (partition by NumeroD, DAY, MONTH, YEAR ) AS TotalAmount
    FROM FORMULAFINAL 
    WHERE Descrip LIKE 'Hector%' 
ORDER BY Ano DESC, NumeroD, Descrip, Descrip1, CodClie, TotalItem, CodUbic, Día_Transaccion, Mes
```

Comment: Yeap It worked, I made it like that but only with the OVER (NumeroD), now I'm looking to count the "NumeroD" by The ClientName to see how many times the client has bought at the store, do you have any idea? .... Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ArnaldoData Add another column to select like `SUM(TotalItem) OVER (partition by NumeroD, DAY, MONTH, YEAR ) AS TotalAmount, COUNT(DISTINCT NumeroD) OVER ( partition by Descrip )
    FROM FORMULAFINAL`

Comment: I cannot upvote due the Reputation :c, but I choose it as the right answer.

Do you have any idea about how to count the fields I wrote you previusly

Comment: @ArnaldoData Look at my comment above

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your last answer.... SQL SERVER told me that I cannot use DISTINCT with OVER :c

Comment: correct. I forgot about that. Use dense rank instead like  below `DENSE_RANK() OVER ( partition by Descrip order by NumeroD) +DENSE_RANK() OVER ( partition by Descrip order by NumeroD desc) -1 as countoforders        FROM FORMULAFINAL`

Comment: DhruvJoshi YOUR ARE GOD, THANKS YOU SO MUCH